# Check if navigation state params object has been set

Tags: react-native, parameters, navigation

I'm trying to do some validation to see if the params object has been set when navigating to my `GetPromoScreen` but it does not work. Here is my sample code:

**HomeScreen** (navigating to GetPromoScreen)

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('GetPromoScreen', { promo: true })
```

**GetPromoScreen** (validating the params object)

```
if(this.props.navigation.state.params.promo != undefined){
    this.setState({ promo: true })
} else {
    this.setState({ promo: false })
}
```

I have an alert dialog from `HomeScreen` where when the user press the button, it will trigger the function where I set the params `promo`. But, If the user closes the alert dialog and straight away entering `GetPromoScreen` from the menu button, the params `promo` will not be set and when that happen, an error will appear saying:

> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating
>   'this.props.navigation.state.params.promo')

My validation code above is not working. Any idea?

Comment: What about `if(this.props.navigation.state.params && this.props.navigation.state.promo){...}`?

Comment: @Milore It works! Thank you! :D:D

Comment: You're welcome. So the problem is that if you do not pass any param, the params object is undefined and it can't access its props (in this case promo).

Answer (score 0):

```
if(this.props.route.params){
        formData.push('profile_id' + "=" + this.props.route.params.profile_id);
    }
```